# Assign vector values to one another

Tags: r

I have two vectors:

```
A = c(letters[1:4])
B = c(1,2,3,4)
```

How can I code so that each value in B is correspondingly assigned to A as such?

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
...
```

Comment: What about a data.frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or:

```
names(B) <- A
```

The result:

```
> B
a b c d 
1 2 3 4 

> B['b']
b 
2
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `assign`

```
for(i in seq_along(A)) assign(A[i], B[i])
a
#[1] 1
```

But it is better to have a named `list` instead of having multiple objects in the global environment i.e.

```
lst <- as.list(setNames(B, A))
```

The element can be extracted

```
lst[['a']]
#[1] 1
```